# Changing the order of worksheets in a workbook using IronPython (or .NET)

Tags: excel, ironpython, com-interop

We've created an API in IronPython that wraps most of the COM functionality w/r/t Excel (and Powerpoint). One of the things we have not yet implemented is the option to change the order of worksheets within a workbook once they've been created. The workflow is basically, create an Excel workbook, then add a bunch of sheets. They become out of order because we loop over similar data segments in the same loop (obviously). So, after all the worksheets are created, how can I modify the order of the sheets?

if you can even point me in the direction of an MSDN page that shows how to do this in .NET I'd appreciate it.

this also helped a great deal:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/sortws.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the Worksheets.Move method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.move%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Looks like exactly what you need